# get clientId through Google analytics reporting API

Tags: java, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

I have noticed that in [Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets), the **clientId** assigned by google analytics itself to uniquely identify a device is not available to query through any of reporting APIs. Does someone know any other possible way which I may got missed, to get the **clientId** in the response body?

here is my sample code

```
DateRange dateRange = new DateRange();
dateRange.setStartDate("2019-04-20");
 dateRange.setEndDate("yesterday");

 // Create the Metrics object.
 Metric sessions = new Metric()
         .setExpression("ga:sessions")
         .setAlias("sessions");

 Dimension userId = new Dimension().setName("ga:dimension1");
 Dimension source = new Dimension().setName("ga:source");
 Dimension medium = new Dimension().setName("ga:medium");
 Dimension campaign = new Dimension().setName("ga:campaign");
 Dimension experimentId = new Dimension().setName("ga:experimentId");

 List<String> filterExpressionList = new ArrayList<>();

 filterExpressionList.add("426"); 
 filterExpressionList.add("359"); 
 filterExpressionList.add("13694118"); 
 filterExpressionList.add("28"); 


 DimensionFilter userIdFilter = new DimensionFilter();
 userIdFilter.setDimensionName("ga:dimension1").setExpressions(filterExpressionList).setCaseSensitive(false).setNot(false).setOperator("IN_LIST");

 List<DimensionFilter> dimensionFilterList = new ArrayList<>();
 dimensionFilterList.add(userIdFilter);

 DimensionFilterClause dimensionFilterClause = new DimensionFilterClause();
 dimensionFilterClause.setFilters(dimensionFilterList);

 List<DimensionFilterClause> dimensionFilterClauses = new ArrayList<>();
 dimensionFilterClauses.add(dimensionFilterClause);
 // Create the ReportRequest object.
 ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest()
         .setViewId(VIEW_ID)
         .setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
         .setMetrics(Arrays.asList(sessions))
         .setDimensions(Arrays.asList(userId,source,medium,campaign,experimentId)).setDimensionFilterClauses(dimensionFilterClauses);

 ArrayList<ReportRequest> requests = new ArrayList<ReportRequest>();
 requests.add(request);

 // Create the GetReportsRequest object.
 GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest()
         .setReportRequests(requests);

 // Call the batchGet method.
 GetReportsResponse response = service.reports().batchGet(getReport).execute();
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: @DaImTo: Attached a sample code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to [cid](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid) passed to the Google analycs data.  The anwser is you cant.  This is not a [dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) returned by the google analytics api this dimension is only used for internal processing.

Your best option would be to add it as a custom dimension and send it with every request you make.

Comment: @DalmTo Thank you. thought on the same (Y).

Comment: sorry about asking here... Can I query and filter the custom variables I set in the event tracking?

Answer (score 4):

clientId is now available through the API as ga:clientId

No need to set clientId (or userId) in a custom dimension any longer.

Note to anyone using the Universal Analytics User ID feature The values returned in ga:clientId is actually the userId Even more interessting. (As of time of writing) GA fails if you request clientId from a User ID view. So you should use a non-User ID view to get the User ID. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Michael Frost Billing. But wonder why it is not listed in Here, Dimensions & Metrics Explorer  : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets